# Since Android 6.0 Audiorecord problems

Tags: android, audio, record

The Error comes here:

```
       mAudioRecord.startRecording();
```

The checking code:

```
private static int[] mSampleRates = new int[]{44100, 22050, 11025, 8000};

public AudioRecord findAudioRecord() {
    for (int rate : mSampleRates) {
        for (short audioFormat : new short[]{AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_8BIT, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT}) {
            for (short channelConfig : new short[]{AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO}) {
                try {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Attempting rate " + rate + "Hz, bits: " + audioFormat + ", channel: " + channelConfig);
                    int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(rate, channelConfig, audioFormat);

                    if (bufferSize != AudioRecord.ERROR_BAD_VALUE) {
                        // check if we can instantiate and have a success
                        AudioRecord recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT, rate, channelConfig, audioFormat, bufferSize);

                        if (recorder.getState() == AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED) {
                            return recorder;
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, rate + "Exception, keep trying.", e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

The Errror:

```
 05-27 16:44:16.371 16055-16254/modseven.shutup E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -1
05-27 16:44:16.381 16055-16254/modseven.shutup E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -1.
05-27 16:44:16.381 16055-16254/modseven.shutup E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
05-27 16:44:16.381 16055-16254/modseven.shutup E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-1320
                                                                 Process: modseven.shutup, PID: 16055
                                                                 java.lang.IllegalStateException: startRecording() called on an uninitialized AudioRecord.
                                                                     at android.media.AudioRecord.startRecording(AudioRecord.java:943)
                                                                     at modseven.shutup.AudioRecorder$3.run(AudioRecorder.java:67)
                                                                     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

It seems to be since Android 6.0.

I can't manage to make it work anymore. It worked before!
I'am also using this:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
```

I didn't change anything on the code. It just stopped working!
Any suggestions? Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Record Audio on Api23 is considered a 'Dangerous Permission' and requires getting the permission at Runtime :

```
<!-- Allows an application to record audio.
     <p>Protection level: dangerous
-->
<permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"
    android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.MICROPHONE"
    android:label="@string/permlab_recordAudio"
    android:description="@string/permdesc_recordAudio"
    android:protectionLevel="dangerous"/>
```

Source : https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml

Have a look here and follow how to request the Permissions at Runtime:

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Alternatively it should work fine if you target Api level 22 when you build your project.